# Schema created in Docker by postgres user does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am building a Docker container for my PostgresSQL 9.4.5 database and I'd like to create the table structures when the container starts.  In the script included in my `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory is this series of commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export PGUSER=postgres
echo "***CREATING DATABASE, USERS, AND ROLES***"
psql <<-EOSQL
    CREATE USER vpager WITH PASSWORD '<pass>';
    CREATE DATABASE vpager;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE vpager TO vpager;
    REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE vpager FROM PUBLIC;
    CREATE ROLE standarduser;
    CREATE USER vpageruser WITH PASSWORD '<pass>';
    \connect vpager
    CREATE SCHEMA ticketing;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA ticketing TO vpager;
    GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE vpager TO standarduser;
    GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ticketing TO standarduser;
    GRANT standarduser TO vpageruser;
EOSQL

echo "***CREATING TABLE STRUCTURES***"
psql -U vpager vpager < /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-vpager-tables.sql
```

The SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE ticketing.merchant
(
  merchant_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  now_serving INT
);

CREATE TABLE ticketing.ticket
(
  ticket_id SERIAL,
  merchant_id INT REFERENCES ticketing.merchant(merchant_id),
  create_ts TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (ticket_id, merchant_id)
);
```

As you can see, the idea is to create a non-privileged user for doing CRUD operations.  The problem is that when the `create-vpager-tables.sql` command runs, it can't see the schema that postgres created:

```
ERROR:  schema "ticketing" does not exist
STATEMENT:  CREATE TABLE ticketing.merchant
        (
          merchant_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
          now_serving INT
        );
ERROR:  schema "ticketing" does not exist
ERROR:  schema "ticketing" does not exist
```

Yet, if I add a `CREATE SCHEMA` statement to the top of `create-vpager-tables.sql`, it says it already exists:

```
ERROR:  schema "ticketing" already exists
```

How do I resolve these errors?  I tried setting my search path at the top of the SQL file, but the same thing happened; it's like a "Schrodinger" schema.

Comment: Looks like although the SCHEMA is being created, however, the script attempts to create tables in that schema *before* SCHEMA creation. Could you merge the two SQLs and run them in a single SQL command? If you can't modify the SQL, you could still pre-pend the SQL string before passing the file to PSQL (in the same command).

Comment: BTW... doesn't look Docker is doing anything here.

Comment: It does work if I put it all in the same command.  However, then I have to go change ownerships of all the tables later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I put the `create-vpager-tables.sql` in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, and apparently the image also tries to source SQL files there.  Moving it to /tmp (and granting `USAGE` on the schema to standarduser) fixed the problem.